# How to capitalize each alternate character of a string?

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift3, swift-playground

Lets say there is a string "johngoestoschool" it should become "JoHnGoEsToScHoOl" and incase if there is a special character in between it should ignore it for example **given string "jo$%@#hn^g*oe!st#os&ch*oo)l" answer should be "Jo$%@#Hn^G*oE!sT#oS&cH*oO)l"**

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39509332/3798182) answer, we in order to iterate we can do:

```
let s = "alpha"
for i in s.characters.indices[s.startIndex..<s.endIndex]
{
    print(s[i])
}
```

Why can't we print the value of "i" here?
When we do i.customPlaygroundQuickLook it types int 0 to int4.

So my idea is to

```
if (i.customPlaygroundQuickLook == 3) {
        s.characters.currentindex = capitalized
}
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your function, the hard part is just checking weather the character is letters or not, using `inout` and replace range would give better performance:

```
func altCaptalized(string: String) -> String {
    var stringAr = string.characters.map({ String($0) }) // Convert string to characters array and mapped it to become array of single letter strings
    var numOfLetters = 0

    // Convert string to array of unicode scalar character to compare in CharacterSet
    for (i,uni) in string.unicodeScalars.enumerated() {
        //Check if the scalar character is in letter character set
        if CharacterSet.letters.contains(uni) { 
            if numOfLetters % 2 == 0 {
                stringAr[i] = stringAr[i].uppercased() //Replace lowercased letter with uppercased
            }
            numOfLetters += 1
        }
    }

    return stringAr.joined() //Combine all the single letter strings in the array into one string
}
```

Comment: "It worked like a charm", only issue is it goes straight over my head, I request you to add comments explaining what you have done with stringAr , What is unicodeScalars functionality here & joined what is it doing?

Comment: Sure, i think its pretty straight forward, its just simply convert the string to array of single letters since it have different type, you also can print each of them to console to see the details

Comment: why are u assign `fifthStr ` back to `fifthStr `? use different name